# How to reuse subquery in T-SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-view

I have a SQL view I'm trying to optimize. The relationship here is one-to-many, one project has many tasks:

```
create view [schema].[vName]
    select p.ProjectId as 'ProjectId'
            -- ...
            -- excluded some selected columns and subqueries where this comment is
            -- ...

            , (select count(t.TaskId)
               from Task t with (nolock)
               where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.IsDeleted = 0) as 'Total_Tasks'
            , (select count(t.TaskId)
               from Task t with (nolock)
               where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and isnull(t.taskowner, 'Unassigned') <> 'Unassigned' and t.IsDeleted = 0) as 'Assigned_Tasks'
            , (select count(t.TaskId)
               from Task t with (nolock)
               where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.TaskStatusId in (400, 500) and
                   t.IsDeleted = 0) as 'Completed_Tasks'
            , (select count(t.TaskId)
               from Task t with (nolock)
               where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) and
                   t.IsDeleted = 0) as 'Remaining_Tasks'
            , (select count(t.TaskId)
               from Task t with (nolock)
               where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.DueDate < getutcdate() and t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) and t.IsDeleted = 0) as 'Late_Tasks'
            , (select (case when count(t.taskid) > 0 then 'Overdue' else 'all' end)
               from Task t with (nolock)
    from project p with (nolock)
    -- there are some additional joined tables here ...
```

As you can see, I'm selecting counts of subsets of the same subquery, over and over again, with the query essentially being:

```
select * from Task where IsDeleted = 0 and Task.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId
```

How can I just reuse this result set then filter from there? I could use a cte, but the problem is I need to know the ProjectId in advanced, so that's not going to quite work. I don't want to use a join because I want each record in this view to be the only record for that project. Are there any suggestions here? Some sort of way I can group these `Tasks` or reuse the result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery which will calculate all of your totals:

```
create view [schema].[vName]
as

select p.ProjectId as 'ProjectId',
    tsk.Total_Tasks, tsk.Assigned_Tasks, tsk.Completed_Tasks, tsk.Remaining_Tasks,
    ...
from project p with (nolock)
    cross apply (
        select count(*) as [Total_Tasks],
            count(case when t.taskowner != 'Unassigned' then 1 end) as [Assigned_Tasks],
            count(case when t.TaskStatusId in (400, 500) then 1 end) as [Completed_Tasks],
            count(case when t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) then 1 end) as [Remaining_Tasks],
            -- Et cetera, ad infinitum...
        from dbo.Task t
        where t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.IsDeleted = 0
    ) tsk
-- there are some additional joined tables here ...
```

Comment: This worked great! dropped my subtree estimated cost in my execution plan from ~26 to 5. Crazy good cost savings, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you only have the one set of groupings, the query can be simplified to this:

```
select p.ProjectId, 
    count(t.TaskId) as Total_Tasks,
    count(case when t.taskowner != 'Unassigned' then 1 end) as Assigned_Tasks,
    count(case when t.TaskStatusId in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Completed_Tasks,
    count(case when t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Remaining_Tasks,
    count(case when t.DueDate < getutcdate() and t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Late_Tasks
from project p with (nolock)
left join dbo.Task t on t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId and t.IsDeleted = 0
group by p.ProjectId
```

If you have multiple tables you are grouping on then you will have to go to a subquery as per the other answer, though there is no reason to use a cross apply over a left join.

```
select p.ProjectId, Total_Tasks, Assigned_Tasks, Completed_Tasks, Remaining_Tasks, Late_Tasks
from project p
left join (
    select
        PrimarySearchEntityId,
        count(TaskId) as Total_Tasks,
        count(case when taskowner != 'Unassigned' then 1 end) as Assigned_Tasks,
        count(case when skStatusId in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Completed_Tasks,
        count(case when t.TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Remaining_Tasks,
        count(case when DueDate < getutcdate() and TaskStatusId not in (400, 500) then 1 end) as Late_Tasks
    from dbo.Task
    where IsDeleted=0
    group by PrimarySearchEntityId
) t on t.PrimarySearchEntityId = p.ProjectId
```

Comment: While I actually liked the idea of a left join better, I just looked into the execution plan, and found that the subtree cost was less in Roger's cross apply answer. But, thanks for the help!

Comment: May depend on indexes etc, but always pays to test! @pdaniels0013